# Instant File Initialisation on Windows Oracle Server

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, tablespaces, datafile

I require to add additional datafiles to a SmallFile tablespace. The process took several minutes on my system for 1 datafile.

Is it possible to allow Oracle the same capability as SQL Server using instant file initialisation? my googling was unproductive.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Oracle does not take advantage of that security policy and always zeroes out the files before writing to them.

I have no idea whether ASM behaves in a different way, but in the filesystem files are always initialized.